# Google sheets, counting words that are all capital, and are a certain length

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula

So lets say i have this string

```
Testing CAP counter and LENGTH li mi TER
```

And I have this formula

```
=COUNTA(REGEXEXTRACT(D2; REPT(".* ([А-ЯA-Z]{3,})";COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(D2;"([А-ЯA-Z]{3,})";"$");"$"))-1)))
```

The intended behavior is that it will count all the words that are all capital, but are 3 or more letters.

But for example, it doesen't count the "TER" in my string.
Also if within the string I write the word "cOUNTER" like this, it will count it.

As far as the second problem is concerned I understand that Im missing some kind of a:

```
SPLIT(D2; " ")
```

Somewhere in there, but I keep getting different errors when I try to plug that in.

And concerning the first issue with "TER", I have no idea. Will someone be able to help me with these issues?

In my region we use ; instead of , in formulas

Comment: Do you mean googlesheets or excel? you have tagged it both.

Comment: I mean google sheets, will edit the tags, I assumed that since a lot functions are interchangeable both tags will be eligible

Comment: Try some work around like `=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(D2;"\b[[:upper:]]{3,}\b";"§ !");"§"))-1`

Comment: @Konata Well there are many, but I have not seen “regexextract()” in the list of excel functions, so not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only had to work with ASCII strings, you could use a simple

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(D2,"\b[[:upper:]]{3,}\b", "§"),"[^§]+",""))
```

where `\b[[:upper:]]{3,}\b` matches a 3+ uppercase letter words in between word boundaries. However, you cannot rely on `\b` that is not Unicode-aware. To enable Unicode letter support you need to use `(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{3,}($|[[:punct:][:space:]])`, but before, to make sure all consecutive matches are found, you need to double all existing delimiters, that is, punctuation or whitespace chars:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A17, "[[:punct:][:space:]]","$0$0"),"(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{3,}($|[[:punct:][:space:]])", "§"),"[^§]+",""))
```

I used `§` as a temporary split char, but you may use `$` (as you are doing now) or any other char that is not likely to appear in your data.

**Details**

- `REGEXREPLACE(A17, "[[:punct:][:space:]]","$0$0")` - matches any punctuation or whitespace char (with `[[:punct:][:space:]]`) and doubles it (with `$0$0` where `$0` refrers to the whole match value)
- `REGEXREPLACE(...,"(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{3,}($|[[:punct:][:space:]])", "§"))` - replaces with `§` all cases of

  - `(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])` - start of string or any punctuation or whitespace char
  - `[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{3,}` - 3 or more uppercase ASCII or Russian uppercase  letters
  - `($|[[:punct:][:space:]])` - end of string or any punctuation or whitespace char
- `REGEXREPLACE(...,"[^§]+","")` - removes all chunks of one or more chars other than `§`
- `=LEN(...)` - gets the length of the resulting string.

Comment: What is the purpose of double `\b`? Will it work with `"[[:upper:]]{3,}"`?

Comment: @MaxMakhrov `\b` is a word boundary, it helps avoid matching `OUNTER` in `cOUNTER`. `"[[:upper:]]{3,}"` without `\b`s will find a match in `cOUNTER`.

Comment: This almost works, thank you! But how would I go about including Cyrillic (Russian) chars in it? Replacing :upper: with А-ЯA-Z didn't do the trick

Comment: @Konata Russian letters can be added as `[[:upper:]А-ЯЁ]`. You may also use `[A-ZА-ЯЁ]`. Do you need Russian or all Cyrillic uppercase letters?

Comment: Neither seem to work, they detect the enlish uppercase words, but not Russian.

Specific string: "Набор машин в STAR ТАКСИ" - outputs as 1

Comment: @Konata Right, that is a problem with word boundaries. You need a bit more sophisticated solution. Let me re-work it.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much for the details of the formula!